# TeXForm on table, how to make empty cells?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, latex

I have the code:

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
l = Append[l, PadLeft[{1}, 3, Null]];
TeXForm[TableForm[l]]
```

Returns

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 1 \\
\end{array}
```

But I am looking to get the last row as

```
  & & 1 \\
```

What is the way to do that, I was hoping that `Null` would be removed. I tried empty string, but it still leads having `\text{}` in the output.

Comment: Export to a string using `ExportString[TexForm[...], "Text"]` and the use `StringReplace[%, "\\text{Null} " -> ""]`?

Comment: Not quite perfect, but what about `""` as placeholder? (This results in `\text{}`, which prints as nothing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an object that TeXForm will treat as an empty string:

```
MakeBoxes[foo, TraditionalForm] ^:= RowBox[{}]
```

Then:

```
TeXForm[TableForm[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {foo, foo, 1}}]]
```

produces:

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  &  & 1 \\
\end{array}
```

which renders as:

\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  &  & 1 \\
\end{array}

Answer (score -2):

Since the invention of 0 by the Indians to save the place between to ciphers in decimal strings against neclection or overwriting, there has to be something in TeX to hold the place

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
l = Append[l, PadLeft[{1}, 3, Esc sq Esc]];

TeXForm[TableForm[l]]

\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \square  & \square  & 1 \\
\end{array}

l
```

[image: array with placeholder]

I justwas  remembering there are other invisible characters treated as symbols, that don'produce \text in TeX. But now the browser interface here is clueless with naked unicode, so that I have it deliver as string.

```
In[82]:= 
TeXForm[ {{1,2,4},{a,b,c},{\[LetterSpace],\[LetterSpace],1}}//TableForm]


  "\begin{array}{ccc}  1 & 2 & 4 \\  a & b & c \\  \unicode{f754} &
  \unicode{f754} & 1 \\ \end{array}"
```

[image]